# Convert all section headers containing specific path pattern in Markdown file to different format

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a Markdown file like this:

```
...
## lib/**/fileA.js
...
## scripts/**/fileB.js
...
## lib/**/fileC.js
...
```

I am looking for a one-liner (preferably one command without pipes) that will replace lines that include paths starting with lib with capitalized basename:

```
...
## FileA
...
## scripts/**/fileB.js
...
## FileC
...
```

Comment: The answer starts with `sed`, the rest left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU sed, possibly others:

```
$ sed -r 's!^## lib/.*/([^/.]+)\.[^/.]+$!## \u\1!' test.md
...
## FileA
...
## scripts/**/fileB.js
...
## FileC
...
```

perl:

```
$ perl -lpe 's{^## lib/.*/([^/.]+)\.[^\.]+$}{## \u$1}' test.md
...
## FileA
...
## scripts/**/fileB.js
...
## FileC
...
```